# Excel macro to make a csv for worksheet with unicode data

Tags: vba, excel, csv, unicode

I am using a macro for making a csv file for each worksheet in my xlsm file.

The is unicode data with around 50000 rows and some columns have dates in them.

By going through cell by cell and appending that data to the csv file is 
taking a lot of time.

**Can you please suggest me some ways to  create a csv file for unicode worksheet with large data?**

Comment: In the macro, Using a file stream with UTF-8 encoding (for writing to the csv file) does the job of preserving the unicode characters, but the csv file creation is very slow for large data like 50000 rows, 10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has the ability to save as a csv file built in already: there is no need for you to code this explicitly. And that will be faster than anything you could code in VBA.

The easiest way to discover how is to use the macro recorder (available on the developer tab) and save your file as a csv.

Comment: The save as to csv doesn't work in case of excel sheet having unicode data like chiunese characters. Those characters will be replaced by random characters like "????". So I used a macro to manually add the data to the csv file

Comment: You can force the saving to be in UTF-8. That *ought* to work.

Comment: There is a `TextCodepage` parameter for `.SaveAs`, but unfortunately, it is ignored and the system locale codepage is used: [SaveAs link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just put the values in an array, and then paste it to the worksheet.

```
Set TheRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(50000, 100))'Set worksheet range
ReDim TempArray(1 To 50000, 1 To 100)
' Fill the temporary array here
->some code to fill our "TempArray"<-
' Copy array to worksheet
TheRange.Value = TempArray
```